# What is (q+1)- homogeneous tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

What is $(q+1)-$Homoheneous tree?

I know that homogeneous tree is a tree in which each vertex has same degree but I don't understand what $(q+1)-$Homoheneous tree means?

Comment: Most likely?  Means a homogeneous tree in which every vertex has degree $q+1$.

Comment: Apparently, this is standard.  Look at the second paragraph in [this book](https://books.google.by/books?id=DozUCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=homogeneous+tree+graph&source=bl&ots=G_s7hwWbAg&sig=hVzedLV1L2b9SnX0qkbGgK1LjOw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiux6GK6crTAhXDCJoKHcHuAMEQ6AEIRzAE#v=onepage&q=homogeneous%20tree%20graph&f=false)